# Separator missing out between list items in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have used a custom array adapter to populate my list view.The problem i face is that the separator is missing out in between the fourth and fifth list item.

Here's the code:

```
public class Clubs extends ListActivity{

    private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private Bitmap mIcon1;
        private Bitmap mIcon2;

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
            // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            // Icons bound to the rows.
            mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.yellow_offline);
            mIcon2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.green_online);
        }

        /**
         * The number of items in the list is determined by the number of speeches
         * in our array.
         *
         * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getCount()
         */
        public int getCount() {
            return DATA.length;
        }

        /**
         * Since the data comes from an array, just returning the index is
         * sufficent to get at the data. If we were using a more complex data
         * structure, we would return whatever object represents one row in the
         * list.
         *
         * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItem(int)
         */
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        /**
         * Use the array index as a unique id.
         *
         * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getItemId(int)
         */
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        /**
         * Make a view to hold each row.
         *
         * @see android.widget.ListAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
         *      android.view.ViewGroup)
         */
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unneccessary calls
            // to findViewById() on each row.
            ViewHolder holder;

            // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
            // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
            // by ListView is null.
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.people_list_item, null);

                // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
                // we want to bind data to.
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textpeople);
                holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
                // and the ImageView.
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
            holder.text.setText(DATA[position]);
            holder.icon.setImageBitmap((position & 1) == 1 ? mIcon1 : mIcon2);

            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView text;
            ImageView icon;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));
    }

    private static final String[] DATA = {
            "Abbaye de Belloc", "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam",
            "Abondance", "Ackawi", "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis",
            };
}
```

Here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget31"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget321"
android:layout_width="479dip"
android:layout_height="54dip"
android:layout_marginTop="16dip"
>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="24dip"
android:layout_height="24dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="14dip"
android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
android:src="@drawable/green_online">
</ImageView>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textpeople"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
android:textColor="#FFF5EE" 
android:layout_height="29dip" 
android:textSize="16sp" 
android:layout_width="400dip" 
android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
>
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the screen shot [image: listseparator]

can someone tell me where i have gone wrong?
Thanks

**EDIT**:
**Solution**:
Here's the code to be added to get it working

```
ListView lv=getListView();
 lv.setDividerHeight(2);
```

Comment: which device you are testing I faced similar issue in HTC tatoo and found that its only device specific

Comment: I am testing it in the emulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the easy way would be to call `setDividerHeight(2)` in your `onCreate` method. In the more complicated way, you need to make sure your resources are correctly put in layout-hdpi / layout because what's happening there is that the OS approximates 1dpi to 0dpi because the app runs in compatibility mode. Also check out your `supports-screens` attribute in your manifest (try setting everything to true)

Comment: can you tell me where to exactly place  the setDividerHeight() in full syntax.I tried putting it in the oncreate.It is throwing me compilation errors.

Comment: You can also try in xml as: android:dividerHeight="3dip"